# Why does cordova throw an error when I want to build my ionic project?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

when i run:
`ionic cordova build --prod android`
the console shows me the following error:

Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

> Configure project :app
> Project evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Ionic\app\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 132
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> No match found

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get
  more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
C:\Ionic\app\platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Project evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Ionic\app\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 132
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> No match found

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get
  more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

```
    cordova.cmd build android exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

**Does anyone know what I may be doing wrong?**

Comment: try to remove platform and re-add it. `ionic cordova platform rm android` then `ionic cordova platform add android@10.1.1`

Comment: HI, thanks to that the problem was solved, but now I have another one, it happens in: app\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 125

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> No match found